# How can I create a multidimensional array by adding data to an exiting array (php)?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code

```
$animal_arr[] = $animals;
$animal_name = $row['name'];
```

Here is my result:

```
Array ( [0] => Cat [1] => Dog)
```

I wish now to add the `animal_name` to the array. I tried to do it like this:

```
array_push($animal_arr, $animal_name);
```

My result is this:

```
Array ( [0] => Fred [1] => Ted [2] => Cat [3] => Dog)
```

In this case the names are not assigned to the animals.
So what I would actually need is something like this maybe:

```
Array (
      [0] => (
            [1] => Fred
            [2] => Cat
         )
      [1] =>  (
            [1] => Ted
            [2] => Dog
         )
)
```

Comment: Use `array_merge_recursive` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: My result for `array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()` is `Array ( [0] => Cat [1] => Dog)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = ( 0 => Cat  , 1 => Dog);
$array2 = ( 0 => Fred , 1 => Ted);

$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

This should do.

Comment: Funny... It outputted `Array ( [0] => cat [1] => dog [2] => fred [3] => ted )` for me.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two arrays, one with animals and the other with names, and you want to merge/rotate these into a specific format.

A peculiar trait of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) makes his easy.

From the PHP docs (see *Example #4 Creating an array of arrays*)

> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the callback function

`array_map()` usually accepts a callback as its first argument, but if you pass `null` instead, like so:

```
<?php

$animals = ['cat', 'dog'];
$names   = ['fred', 'ted'];

$merged = array_map(null, $names, $animals);

print_r($merged);
```

You ge he following resul:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => fred
            [1] => cat
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ted
            [1] => dog
        )

)
```

Which I believe is what you are looking for. Hope this helps :)